# PHP/ Laravel: How to Give An If Statement a Dynamic Condition?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, laravel-5.1

Within the my Quotation module, Products can be grouped under a variety of different categories. Categories can also be created and deleted. The code below works fine but only because I have hardcoded the categories. You will see that if category_id = 1, then show products belonging to "cars". If it is "2", then show "motorcycles".

This is completely inflexible. I want to be able to dynamically create a new category, and have that new category presented on my form. So what can I do, if anything, to allow the dynamic creation or deletion of a category ?

I am using Laravel, however, a PHP answer is just as good.

The code is a Laravel View but I think it is pretty obvious what is going on:

```
   @foreach($quotation as $quote)
            @if($quote->category_id == 1)
                <tr>
                <td>{!! Form::select('product_id[0]',$products['cars'], $quote->name, ['class'=>'product_id']) !!}</td>
                <td>{!!Form::text('quantity',$quote->quantity) !!}</td>
                <td id="price">{{$quote->price}}</td>
                <td id="cost">{{$quote->cost}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif


            @if($quote->category_id == 4)
                <tr>
                <td>{!! Form::select('product_id[0]',$products['motorcycle'], $quote->name, ['class'=>'product_id']) !!}</td>
                <td>{!!Form::text('quantity',$quote->quantity) !!}</td>
                <td id="price">{{$quote->price}}</td>
                <td id="cost">{{$quote->cost}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
 public function quote_edit($id)
{
    $customer = $this->quotation->get_customer($id); //array
    $products = $this->quotation->get_products(); //array of collections
    $quotation = $this->quotation->get_quote($id);  //array
    $count = count($quotation);
    return View('quotations/edit_quote_test2', compact('count','quotation', 'products', 'customer') ) ;
}
```

Model:

```
   public function get_quote($id){

    return DB::table('quotations')
        ->join('products', 'products.product_id', '=', 'quotations.product_id')
        ->select( 'products.name','products.category_id','products.price','quotations.product_id','quotations.quantity','quotations.cost','quotations.reference')
        ->where('quotations.reference', '=', $id)
        ->get();
}
```

Here is a sample of the print_r() results for $products

```
{id: "7",
name: "Stanley Hook Blades 11-939",
product_id: "3463",
description: null,
long_description: null,
price: "62.00",
category_id: "7",
color: null,
coverage: null,
barcode: null,
qrcode: null,
box_quantity: null,
supplier_id: "1",
location_id: null,
alternate_id: null,
created_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
updated_at: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
category_name: "tools"
}
```

Here is a sample of the print_r() results for Quotation:

```
{
name: "asphalt",
category_id: "9",
category_name: "tear_install",
price: "300.00",
product_id: "3453",
quantity: "1",
cost: "300.00",
reference: "jac310316-75",
total: "15900.00"
}
```

Comment: The only difference between the two variations seems to be in the producs array, so why don't you retrieve the category name when retrieving the `$quote` model. Then you can call the right value within `$producs` like `$products[$quote->category_name]`. If you post your controller/model I can help you with that.

Comment: @JasperVergers  Controller and model added as per request.. I'm old school, I don't like eloquent. Many Thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

You can join `category table` with `category_id`. I assume you have table name category with autoincrement column category_id and category_name column for name so you can use that column in select statement.

Model:

```
   public function get_quote($id){

    return DB::table('quotations')
        ->join('products', 'products.product_id', '=', 'quotations.product_id')
        ->leftJoin('category', 'category.category_id', '=', 'product.category_id')     
        ->select( 'products.name','products.category_id', 'category.category_name','products.price','quotations.product_id','quotations.quantity','quotations.cost','quotations.reference')
        ->where('quotations.reference', '=', $id)
        ->get();
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($quotation as $quote)
                <tr>
                <td>{!! Form::select('product_id[0]',$products[$quote->category_name], $quote->name, ['class'=>'product_id']) !!}</td>
                <td>{!!Form::text('quantity',$quote->quantity) !!}</td>
                <td id="price">{{$quote->price}}</td>
                <td id="cost">{{$quote->cost}}</td>
                </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have been slow to come back to you on this, as I have been trying to solve it myself without any success.   

The problem lies with $products[$quote->category_name].  $quote->category_name is coming back as an undefined index. Strangely it is defined within the get_quote query. 

I have added the print_r() results for both $products and $quotation. Any thoughts you have are very welcome !  

Many thanks !